# Animating image in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Loving fabric and trying to get to grips with it all.

My overall goal is to display a well being drilled. I have many many questions but the first of which is 'how can i animate the image object?'

I have:

```
var drillBit = new fabric.Image.fromURL('assets/images/drillBit.jpg',function(img){
    img.scale(0.5).set({left:400, top:0});
    canvas.add(img);
});
```

and then I call:

```
(function animate() {
    canvas.item(9).top+=1;
    canvas.renderAll();
    fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(animate);
})();
```

If i replace the item index with another so that it represents text or a rect it works fine but nothing when i select the image.  Can someone explain please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kangax answered this on the Google group.

Solution is to:

```
var drillBit = new fabric.Image.fromURL('assets/images/drillBit.jpg',function(img){
img.scale(0.5).set({left:400, top:0});
canvas.add(img);
//animate the drill
(function animate() {
    img.top+=1;
    canvas.renderAll();
    fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(animate);
})();
});
```